# Not able to send email using JavaMail, Exchange Server and SMTP

Tags: smtp, exchange-server, jakarta-mail

I am trying below code to send mail using JavaMail, Exchange Server and SMTP:

```
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);

            Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username,
                            password);
                }
            });

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(to));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC,
                    InternetAddress.parse(cc));
            message.setSubject(sub);

            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart1.setContent(msg, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);

            message.setContent(multipart);

            Transport.send(message);
```

Getting below error, please help:

> com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Client does not
>   have permissions to send as this sender Exception has been thrown :
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Client does not
>   have permissions to send as this sender

I have changed the user details on 7th Jul 2014 and now getting below error:

> Exception has been thrown : javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection
>   dropped by server?;   nested exception is:  java.io.IOException:
>   Connection dropped by server?

Answer (score 0):

What version of JavaMail are you using?  What does the protocol trace show?  Are you sure you're authenticating to the server?

If you're using an older version of JavaMail, you'll need to set the properties as strings, not boolean constants.

Comment: I am using JavaMail 1.5.1.
All the details like credentials, authentication are absolutely correct.
Added the error details in my question.

Comment: Can you post the [protocol trace](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug)?